# rosinstall behind Proxy

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, build-from-source, pandaboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently trying to install ROS on the Pandaboard ES behind a proxy. The board runs Ubuntu 11.10 (server prebuild) and is working so far.
But I'm running into failures by proceeding the installationguide for fuerte from source.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

I'm doing everything the same as in the tutorial but when it comes to the point of installing the second layer:
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

I get the following failure and not a single package gets installed
Error processing 'NAME OF XY PACKAGE' : local variable 'tempdir' referenced before assignment

I set the environment as following
http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy.xxxx.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=ftp://user:pass@proxy.xxxx.com:8080/
https_proxy=https://user:pass@proxy.xxxx.com:8080/

and everything like wget,git,apt-get is functioning but i think the proxy is still blocking the rosinstall procedure.

Would be great to get some help here.
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35213/rosinstall-behind-proxy/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosinstall calls out to svn, git, bzr, or hg depending on what repositories you are trying to pull down.  If you can make sure that those commands work, then rosinstall should start working.

If you can't get them to work using the environment, another possibility is to setup a squid transparent proxy.  There are quite a few howtos if you [search google](https://www.google.com/search?q=squid+transparent+proxy)

---

A few notes, as I recently had to deal with this:

**Git Proxies**

Git has it's own command line flag for proxies, and can be set by executing the following:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

**Subversion Proxies**

Subversion's proxies can be set through the `~/.svn/servers` file in the `[global]` section:

```
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
http-proxy-host = proxy.server.com
http-proxy-port = 8080
# http-proxy-username = proxyuser
# http-proxy-password = proxypwd
```

**Wget Proxies**

Wget and curl both acknowledge the `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `ftp_proxy` that you mention above.

**Mercurial Proxies**

Mercurial should acknowledge the command line `http_proxy`, but if it doesn't, you can always set up your hgrc file.

[http_proxy]
host = proxy.server.com:8080
user = proxy user
passwd = proxypwd

**APT Proxies**

Apt should acknowledge the command line `http_proxy`.

**With SUDO**

sudo will clear out your proxy environment variables by default (meaning no proxy with any sudo'ed (sudid?) commands).  To prevent this from happening, add the following to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2